# How do I add high level tests to lock down behavior before refactoring?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, refactoring

I have a moderately sized, highly tangled, messy, big ball-of-mud project that I want to refactor. It is about 50k lines of code and I am the only maintainer. One class is 10k LOC long with line widths of 400 characters. Features are still being added, albeit slowly. I feel good about the refactoring part. Ripping apart code is very comfortable to me. However, getting a set of tests around the application to ensure that I don't break it seems daunting. Huge object graphs and mocking out all the databases will be real buggers. I probably could get away with doing massive refactoring without breaking things horribly. But, prudence dictates some level of tests to ensure at least some level of safety. At the same time, I don't want to spend any more than a minimal amount of time getting a set of "behavior lock-down" tests around the code. I fully intend to add a full set of unit tests once I get things a bit decoupled. A rewrite is a non-starter.

Does anyone have any pointers or techniques? Has anyone done this sort of thing before?

Comment: This probably belongs on Programmers, but in any case: No matter what you do, it will be a pain. I'd suggest starting in the safest place you can, and testing carefully before you make any changes. The tests will be painful and plentiful, but it's that or leave it as is.

Comment: I would start refactoring at a bottleneck - perhaps there is a particular class that accesses the database?  And then build in the tests from there.  Refactoring time is probably going to be 900% more useful than trying to put tests on a (probably) untestable structure.

Answer (score 0):

**Mindset**

Generally it can be tough going trying to write automated tests (even high level ones) for applications that were not build with testability in mind.

The best thing is going to be make sure you are disciplined in writing tests as you refactor (which it sounds like you are intending to be). This will slowly turn that ball of code, into an elegant dancing unicorn of well encapsulated testable classes.

**Suggestions**

Start with creating some manual high level tests (e.g. user goes to page one, clicks on the red button, then a textbox appears..) to have a starting point. Depending on the technology the app is built in there are a few frameworks out there that can help automate these high level (often UI driven) tests:

For web apps [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) is a great choice, for WPF apps you can use the [UI Automation framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for other application, while its a bit rudimentary, [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) can be a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

Here how I do it in c++ (and c-).

1. Create a directory to house the tests, cd to this directory
2. Create a directory to house mock objects, say mock-objs.
3. Create a makefile to compile all object files of interest.
4. Add necessary include directories or mock .h files to make all object file compile.
5. Congratulate yourself you are 90% done.
6. Add a test harness of your choice (e.g. cppunit, atf-tests, google test ..).
7. Add a null test case - just start, log and declare success.
8. Add necessary libraries and/or mock .c/.cpp files until link is successful and the very first test passes. Note: all functions in these .c/.cpp mock files should contain only a primitive to fail the test when called.
9. Congratulate yourself you are 99% done.
10. Add a primitive event scheduler: say just list of callbacks - so you can post request and receive response from event callback.
11. Add a primitive timer: say timer wheel or even timer list if you need just a few timers.
12. Write advance-time function: (a) process all queued events (b)increment current time to the next tick, (c)expire all timers waiting for this tick, (d)process all queued events over and over again until no events left, (e) if end the time advance is not reached go to step(b).
13. Congratulate yourself: now you can add tests with relative ease: add a test case, modify mock functions as required, repeat.